# Equivalent of unset using jinput

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput

How can I do the below using Joomla API `JFactory::getApplication()->input;`

```
unset($_GET["variable1"]);
```

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** there is no equivalent, because it's not needed.

`JInput` data is by default a reference to `$_REQUEST`, so it dosen't have own unset method, because it is not needed.  Although it would be nice to have `$input->unset('variable1');` for completness of API.

You should use plain PHP, e.g `unset($_REQUEST['variable1']);`. If you have your variable in `$_GET`, you can unset by that, if you prefer.

Although you can always use `$input->set('variable1', null);`, but this way PHP carbage collector won't free memory, since variable is still defined.

Comment: @Malaiselvan This seems like a complete and accurate answer.  Is there any reason not to accept this answer?